# How to add the value of selectbox to a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 select box and i want to add value of them to a selectbox based onchange selectbox. i wrote the below code. but it is working only for one .
how can i do this ?
here is my code :

```js
var selectBox = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var selectBox2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
selectBox2.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
                           
function handleChange()
{
    var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('myInput').value = selectedValue;
    document.getElementById('myInput2').value = selectedValue;

}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect2">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<input type="text" id="myInput2" />
```

Comment: Do you want to append the new values to the current value on textbox or do you want one textbox mapped to a select element?

Comment: @NisargShah i want to append the value of selectbox to selectbox when selected

Comment: Something like `Option 2, Option 3`?

Comment: @NisargShah yes , it is working now .the problem is when i select from first selectbox it append to all textboxes. i want to separate to each of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var selectBox = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var selectBox2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
selectBox2.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
                           
function handleChange(event)
{
    if (event.target.id == "mySelect") {
      document.getElementById('myInput').value = selectBox.value;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('myInput2').value = selectBox2.value;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect2">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<input type="text" id="myInput2" />
```

Comment: for the first time when in first selectbox when selected it appended to all textboxes . and it is not correct. i want to add value of "myselect" to "myInput" and   "myselect2" to "myInput2"

Comment: do you mean when you first run the code you want the value to be appended?

Comment: i just want to show the value "myselect" to "myInput" textbox and "myselect2"  to "myInput2" textbox. based of onchange each selectbox

Comment: i have shorten the code, you can take a look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with jquery I might as well provide a jquery based answer:

```
$('[id^=mySelect]').change(function(){
  $('#'+this.id.replace('Select','Input')).val($(this).val())
});
```

This short snippet should do all you want. My first selector `[id^=mySelect]` will select *all* ids starting with 'mySelect' which can be useful if you want to extend the scope of this snippet to further selects and inputs. If this is not what you want you could replace it with the more explicit version `#mySelect,#mySelect1`.